# Creating textbox as array type in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

**CakePHP Code**

```
<?php echo $this->Form->hidden("name",array("value"=>$table['name']));?>
```

**Output of above code**

```
<input type="hidden" id="KPIName" value="Customer Acquisition" name="data[KPI][name]">
```

But I want following output

```
<input type="hidden" id="KPIName" value="Customer Acquisition" name="data[KPI][name][]">
```

How can I achieve in CakePHP? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with -

```
<?php echo $this->Form->hidden("name.",array("value"=>$table['name']));?>
```

Comment: Your code generates following output : `<input type="hidden" id="KPIName[]" value="Customer Acquisition" name="data[KPI][name[]]">`

Comment: add a dot `.`. Updated the answer

Comment: Now output is : `<input type="hidden" id="name[]" value="Customer Acquisition" name="data[name][[]]">`